# How to use regexp_substr() with group of delimiter characters?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string something like this 'SERO02~~~NA_@ERO5'. I need to sub string it using delimiter **~~~**. So can get SERO02 and NA_@ERO5 as result.

I create an regex experession like this:

```
select regexp_substr('SERO02~~~NA_@ERO5' ,'[^~~~]+',1,2) from dual;
```

It worked fine and returns : NA_@ERO5

But if I change the string to ERO02~NA_@ERO5 the result is still same.
But I expect the expression to return nothing since delimiter **~~~** is not found in that string. Can someone help me out to create correct expression?

Comment: `[^~~~]+` means match 1 or more characters other than `~`. It is equal to `[^~]+`

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want all elements.  Handles NULL elements too:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select 'SERO02~~~NA_@ERO5' from dual
    )
    select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(~~~|$)', 1, level, null, 1) element
    from tbl
    connect by  level <= regexp_count(str, '~~~') + 1;

ELEMENT
-----------------
SERO02
NA_@ERO5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

`[^~~~]` matches a single character that is not one of the characters following the caret in the square brackets. Since all those characters are identical then `[^~~~]` is the same as `[^~]`.

You can match it using:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         'SERO02~~~NA_@ERO5',
         '~~~(.*?)(~~~|$)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which will match `~~~` then store zero-or-more characters in a capture group (the round brackets `()` indicates a capture group) until it finds either `~~~` or the end-of-string. It will then return the first capture group.

Comment: It returns the second appearance as result, I think it is because 'NA_@ERO5' is between ~~~ and end-of-string. But changing 'th_appearance ' parameter is not returning other sub strings. Is it possible to retrieve other matches?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regular expressions, with a bit of logics:

```
with test(text) as ( select 'SERO02~~~NA_@ERO5' from dual)
select case
         when instr(text, '~~~') != 0 then
            substr(text, instr(text, '~~~') + 3)
         else
            null
         end
from test
```

This will give the part of the string after `'~~~'`, if it exists, `null` otherwise.
You can edit the `ELSE` part to get what you need when the input string does not contain `'~~~'`.
Even using regexp,to match the string `'~~~'`, you need to write it exactly, without `[]`; the `[]` is used to list a set of characters, so `[aaaaa]` is exactly the same than `[a]`,while `[abc]` means `'a' OR 'b' OR 'c'`.

With regexp, even if not necessary, one way could be the following:

```
substr(regexp_substr(text, '~~~.*'), 4)
```

Comment: Try it with `ABC~~~DEF~~~GHI` both your queries will return `DEF~~~GHI` which is not the same as the regular expression match the OP has described in the text.